# c connect() error - invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, connect

I'm writing a simple UDP client and an error returned as "invalid argument", but I don't know what's wrong. It is compiled on linux. My code is as below.

```
int udp_fd = -1;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int port = 1701;

udp_fd = socket(AF_PPPOX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (udp_fd < 0) {
    printf("fail to get UDP socket\n");
    return 0;
}

memset((char *) &addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("31.25.210.118");
addr.sin_port = htons(port);

if(connect(udp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0 ) {
    printf("UDP connect failed, errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is compiled on linux, I don't know if it's time error or not. How do I check?

Comment: Is the compiler saying anything? What compiler do you use? Could you paste the result of `gcc -Wall yourclient.c`?

Comment: I just tried this code, it's a runtime error, connect() failed "because" the type of the socket is AF_PPPOX. I tried with AF_INET, it works fine. I think AF_PPPOX sockets have to be handled differently.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an `AF_INET` address with an `AF_PPPoX` socket. This is mixing apples and parakeets.

PPP stands for "point-to-point", there is no such thing as IP address in this domain. Pick your game. You either connect over the Internet, and use `socket(AF_INET, ...`, or connect over PPP and use one of the PPP protocols like `PX_PROTO_OLAC` or `PX_PROTO_OPNS`, and a corresponding socket address type (`sockaddr_pppolac` or `sockaddr_pppopns`) instead of `sockaddr_in`.